# How to use AfterMap to map properties on collection property

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two entities and two DTOs. I am mapping the entities to the DTOs. Simplified versions of the DTOs look like:

```
public class FooDto {
     // Other properties removed for clarity.
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public decimal Total { get; set; }
     public ICollection<BarDto> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarDto {
     // Other properties removed for clarity.
     public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

The `Foo` and `Bar` classes are:

```
public class Foo {

     public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    // Unimportant properties
}
```

***The Mapping***

I am mapping this in a method as:

```
public FooDto Map(IMapper mapper, Foo foo) {

        // _fooTotalService and _barTotalService injected elsewhere by DI.

        return mapper.Map<Foo, FooDto>(foo, opt =>
        {
            opt.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
            {
                dest.Total = _fooTotalService.GetTotal(src);
                dest.Bars.Total = ?????? // Needs to use _barTotalService.CalculateTotal(bar)
            });
        });
}
```

AutoMapper already has mappings configured for Foo to FooDto and Bar to BarDto which are working fine.

I need to update each BarDto in FooDto with a total using a service (the reasons for which are too lengthy to go into - suffice to say it needs to happen this way).

What syntax do I need to use in `AfterMap` to map each `Total` property of `BarDto` using the `_barTotalService.CalculateTotal(bar)` method, where `bar` is the `Bar` in question?

Note that the `_barTotalService.CalculateTotal` method takes an instance of `Bar` not `BarDto`.

Comment: `Total` is a property of `BarDto`. `FooDto.Bars` cannot have the property. Also how is `bar` passed in `_barTotalService.CalculateTotal(bar)`?

Comment: `FooDto` has a collection called `Bars` of type `BarDto`.  In turn each `BarDto` has a property called `Total`.  I need to set this `Total` property using the instances of `Bar` contained on the original `Foo` object being mapped.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work -

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
            {
                dest.Total = 8;//service call here
                for (var i = 0; i < dest.Bars.Count; i++)
                {
                    dest.Bars.ElementAt(i).Total = 9;//service call with src.Bars.ElementAt(i)
                }
            });
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDto>();
var t = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<FooDto>(new Foo
        {
            Bars = new List<Bar> { new Bar { } }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, but I don't think this will work.  The service call takes an instance of `Bar` not `BarDto`.  The `for` loop is iterating over the destination collection of `BarDto`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `TypeConverter`, those are classes that can have dependency injection in their constructors. So you inject the services there, and use something like `ConstructUsing` after `CreateMap`.